# How can I access objects in a loop?

Tags: java

I am trying to hand over the position value of my object 'next' to the next 'next' object. Is it possible to write this code as a loop and scale it by n?

```java
next.next.next.next.pos.y = next.next.next.pos.y;
next.next.next.next.pos.x = next.next.next.pos.x;
next.next.next.pos.y = next.next.pos.y;
next.next.next.pos.x = next.next.pos.x;
next.next.pos.y = next.pos.y;
next.next.pos.x = next.pos.x;
next.pos.x = pos.x;
next.pos.y = pos.y;
```

Comment: "*Is it possible to write this code as a loop and scale it by n?*" - Most probably, yes.

Comment: Using a doubly linked list might make this easier. You could also use recursion or a stack. The question is - why not just add a new element at the head and save all this copying around?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and tip! My homework is to create a snake game and I had to create those objects in a private void extend method, so I have to access them now again in the private void move method.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear. What your code above does is move the data in each object to the object after it. The question is, instead of doing that, why not just add a new object before the other objects? Perhaps more context on what this does (add to your question) will help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this:

```
while(obj.next != null) {
  obj.next.pos.x = obj.pos.x;
  obj.next.pos.y = obj.pos.y;
  obj = obj.next;
}
```

Later edit:

Sorry, I misunderstood your question.

You could then use a list to solve this issue. It's not the most performant way to do it but I will work.

```
List<Obj> objs = new ArrayList<>();

objs.add(obj);

// Add everything to a list
while(obj.next != null) {
    objs.add(obj.next);
    obj = obj.next;
}

// Walk the list in the reverse order
for(i = objs.size() - 1; i > 1 ; i--) {
  objs[i].pos.x = objs[i - 1].pos.x;
  objs[i].pos.y = objs[i - 1].pos.y;
}
```

Comment: Nope, because this will erase the next-next before you have had chance to copy it (e.g. 1→2→3→4 becomes 1→1→1→1 instead of 1→1→2→3). The problem here is that you have to start from the end and move backwards so as not to lose information.

Comment: `while(obj.next != null) {
    objs.add(obj.next);
}` object.next is never null if it enters the loop once. You forgot to do: `obj = obj.next`